What is the fastest way to overwrite everything on SD card with 0s
I have this class method that handles the writing of 0s to an SD card via dd:
    def run(self):
        try:
            print("[DEBUG] Starting zeroing process...")
            # Get the size of the device
            size_output = subprocess.check_output(['blockdev', '--getsize64', self.selected_device]).decode().strip()
            device_size = int(size_output)

            # Start the dd process
            dd_process = subprocess.Popen(
                ['dd', 'if=/dev/zero', f'of={self.selected_device}', 'bs=16M', 'status=progress'],
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                universal_newlines=True
            )

            # Regex to capture progress information
            progress_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+) bytes')

            for line in dd_process.stderr:
                print(f"[DEBUG] dd output: {line.strip()}")
                match = progress_pattern.search(line)
                if match:
                    bytes_written = int(match.group(1))
                    progress_value = min(int((bytes_written / device_size) * 100), 100)
                    print(f"[DEBUG] Zeroing progress: {progress_value}%")
                    self.zero_progress_update.emit(progress_value)

            # Wait for the dd process to finish
            dd_process.wait()

            # Check if the process completed successfully or with the expected "No space left on device" error
            dd_stderr_output = dd_process.stderr.read()
            if dd_process.returncode != 0:
                print("Returned an error code...")
                if "No space left on device" in dd_stderr_output:
                    print("[DEBUG] No space left on device, zeroing process completed successfully.")
                    self.zero_progress_update.emit(100)
                    self.finished.emit()
                else:
                    print("Passing error code into exception handler")
                    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(dd_process.returncode, 'dd', output=dd_stderr_output)
            else:
                print("[DEBUG] Zeroing process completed successfully.")
                self.finished.emit()

        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            # Handle CalledProcessError properly
            error_output = e.output if e.output else str(e)
            if "No space left on device" in error_output:
                print("[DEBUG] Zeroing process completed successfully (device fully written).")
                self.zero_progress_update.emit(100)
                self.finished.emit()
            else:
                print(f"[ERROR] Exception occurred during zeroing (scenario 1): {error_output}")
                self.error_occurred.emit(error_output)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"[ERROR] Exception occurred during zeroing (scenario 2): {str(e)}")
            self.error_occurred.emit(str(e))

Writing to the SD card until runs out of space is a pretty time consuming process though.
I initially was using bs=4M and tried bumping it up to bs=16m but I honestly don't think it made a difference.
I also tried adding these:
            # Start the dd process
            dd_process = subprocess.Popen(
                ['dd', 'if=/dev/zero', f'of={self.selected_device}', 'bs=16M', 'oflag=direct', 'conv=fdatasync', 'status=progress'],
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                universal_newlines=True
            )

But I think it made things even slower somehow, or at the very least it made no noticeable improvements.
Is there anything that can be done or does this entirely depend on the actual SD card being used?

I'm not exactly sure what status=progress means, but if it means that you are telling dd to draw a progress bar or something like that, it certainly is slower than if it didn't do that. In general, all the output parsing and progress reporting makes it slower.

Yes, writing to SD is slow.  When you consider the size of modern cards it can take a long time indeed.  The laws of physics may be working against you here.

As already said writing to SD cards can be quit slow in general. They are rated for particular speeds/usecases, and that’s then essentially the limit you have for writing/reading. Another factor is that depending on the hardware that reads/writes to the SD they can get quite hot while writing which could also impact the writing speed.

Have you done the math?  A "UHS-1" SD card writes 100MB/s.  A 64GB card will thus take 11 minutes.  There's no magic here.

In my experience, there's rarely any appreciable benefit beyond writing 128kB blocks but try benchmarking it for your hardware.

good comments here. maybe also check, blkdiscard (for some SSDs and some SD cards) -- sudo blkdiscard -s /dev/sdX  -- may give u little speed up compared to dd command.
shred is another tool that can be faster than dd for overwriting data, may worth checking out.

How fast is your current way and how fast is the card supposed to be?

My SD cards are Panasonics that range from 32gb to 64gb and on average it's about 33.3MB/s , which is pretty cool that that is what it averages to lol
I have a PyQT5 gui where I can select what image I want to write to what SD card, and it has a progress bar (and outputs messages to terminal) because otherwise there is no way of knowing how much work was completed
The reason I want to write 0s to the SD cards is because sometimes I noticed the writing would significantly slow down on certain cards during different steps of the image writing process
But writing 0s takes a long time :(
